# javascript function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a php page which dynamically produces this;

```
...
<select name='sales_id'>
<option>
<option onclick='select_person(2)'>name1
<option onclick='select_person(3)'>name2
<option onclick='select_person(4)'>name3
</select>
<h2 style='text-align:center;font-size:120%;'>Planned Activities</h2>
<table  width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>
<th>Week Opened</th><th>Week Closed</th><th>Company<br>
<select name='text'>
<option>
<option onclick='filter_company(comp1)'>comp1
<option onclick='filter_company(comp2)'>comp2
<option onclick='filter_company(comp3)'>comp3
<option onclick='filter_company(comp4)'>comp4
<option onclick='filter_company(comp5)'>comp5
</select>
...
```

In the js file I have ;

```
function select_person(userid) {
    var link="welcome.php?sales_id="+userid;
    document.location.href=link;
}

function filter_company(company) {
    var link="welcome.php?filter=company&text="+company;
    document.location.href=link;
}
```

The select_person function works but for some reason the filter_company function does not. I am at a loss!

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! It's passing the info now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote the arguments passed to `filter_company` so that they are interpreted as string literals, not variables.

```
<option onclick='filter_company("comp1")'>comp1
<option onclick='filter_company("comp2")'>comp2
<option onclick='filter_company("comp3")'>comp3
<option onclick='filter_company("comp4")'>comp4
<option onclick='filter_company("comp5")'>comp5
```

Comment: That said, you should really use the `<select>`'s `onchange` event instead.

Comment: and you should not use dom0 events

Comment: I didn't even know it would work; I'm a little surprised. (That I'm wrong, however, not as surprising.)

Comment: Thanks Raynos, could you elaborate on this dom0 issue?

Comment: @tjohnson_nb dom0 = inline event handlers (that is, in the HTML). Better to use dom2: [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)/[`attachEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent).

Answer (score 4):

Pass in comp1 as a string, e.g.

`onclick="filter_company('comp1')"`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a number to the select_person function. You *think* you are passing the text 'comp1' etc to the select_company function but you are actually passing an empty variable.